# Должно ли быть тире?

Tags: пунктуация

**Меркуцио самый мечтательный.**

Тут нужно тире или нет?

Answer (score 2):

**Меркуцио самый мечтательный.**

По основному правилу тире **не ставится**, так как сказуемое выражено формой прилагательного.

Но возможна постановка **авторского тире** при наличии паузы, если нужно выделить подлежащее (например, при описании нескольких лиц).

Правило: [§ 5. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92)

10. Если сказуемое выражено прилагательным (в том числе местоименным) или предложно-именным сочетанием, **тире перед сказуемым обычно не ставится**: Погода несносная, дорога скверная, ямщик упрямый… (П.); Земля велика и прекрасна (Ч.); Вишнёвый сад мой! (Ч.); Небо без единого облачка; Люди здесь необыкновенной доброты.
    Тире перед сказуемым-прилагательным ставится:
    1) **при логическом или интонационном членении** предложения:Зрачки — кошачьи, длинные (Ш.); Высота возле разбросанных домиков хутора — командная (Каз.);